# Displaying multiple lines of user input in tkinter with Text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, user-input, tkinter-text

I am having trouble getting multiple lines from user input and displaying it back to them. I'm using OOP to make a window to have user input their essay and one to display it back to them.
When I use the `.get()`, nothing appears. Any suggestions?

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
class userInterface:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def uploadWindow(self):
        #Generic window that is used for each new window 
        self.essayAdd = tkinter.Tk()
        self.essayAdd.geometry("1500x900")
        self.essayAdd.title("Text Analysis")
        self.essayAdd.mainloop

    def copyPasteCommand(self):
        #Creates a new window with space to copy and paste text
        self.uploadWindow()
        #Title of window
        tkinter.Label(self.essayAdd, text = "Uploading your essay", fg = "white", bg = "purple", font=("Helvetica", 20)).pack(fill = "x")

        #Creating an input for user to paste their essay
        tkinter.Label(self.essayAdd, text="Please paste your essay below.", font=("Helvetica", 16)).place(x = 50, y=40)
        self.userEssayLabel = Text()
        self.scrollBar = Scrollbar(self.essayAdd)
        self.scrollBar.config(command=self.userEssayLabel.yview)
        self.userEssayLabel.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollBar.set)
        self.scrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.userEssayLabel.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.userEssay = self.userEssayLabel.get("1.0", END)
        #Creating buttons to quit and move on to next step
        #Quit
        self.quitting = tkinter.Button(self.essayAdd, text = "Quit", fg = "purple", font =("Helvetica", 16), command = self.essayAdd.destroy).place(x=50, y=600)
        #Next step
        self.enter = tkinter.Button(self.essayAdd, text = "Enter", fg = "purple", font =("Helvetica", 16), command = self.essayWindow).place(x=1235, y=600)


    def essayWindow(self):
        self.essayAdd.destroy()
        self.uploadWindow()
        tkinter.Label(self.essayAdd, text = "Essay Analysis", fg = "white", bg = "purple", font=("Helvetica", 20)).pack(fill = "x")
        tkinter.Label(self.essayAdd, text = self.userEssay, fg = "white", bg = "purple", font=("Helvetica", 16)).place(x=1235, y=600)

execute = userInterface()
execute.copyPasteCommand()
```

Comment: Missing () at the line `self.essayAdd.mainloop` inside `uploadWindow()`.  But if you add back the missing (), then statements after `self.uploadWindow()` in `copyPasteCommand()` function will not be executed due to  `mainloop()`.  You need to refactor your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `self.userEssayLabel.get("1.0", END)` just a few milliseconds after you create the text widget, well before the user has had a chance to enter any data.

You need to wait to call the `get` method until you actually need the contents of the widget, and not before.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to fix and a few things I would change.

1. `self.essayAdd.mainloop` does nothing here. You need to add the `()` at the end like this: `self.essayAdd.mainloop()`.
2. `self.userEssay = self.userEssayLabel.get("1.0", END)` is not happening when you think. This only happens the instance your code is ran and never again. So it basically has an empty string assigned to `self.userEssay`.
3. I would not use `place()` for buttons and labels. `place()` has its place as it were but for the most part you will want to use `grid()` or `pack()` for the majority of your widget placement.
4. You are overusing `self.`. The prefix `self.` is used to id class attributes and the only time something needs to be a class attribute is if it will be accessed form a separate method than it was created in or by code outside of the class.
5. You are using both `import tkinter` and `from tkinter import *` when you only need one. The preferred method is `import tkinter as tk`. Then you simply use the `tk` prefix anywhere you need to.
6. Seeing that you are using a class I would inherit from `Tk()` instead of doing `self.essayAdd = tkinter.Tk()`. We can manage things easier this way and get all the functionality we need in the class.

All that said here is your code cleaned up a bit. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk


class UserInterface(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('1500x900')
        self.title('Text Analysis')
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.main_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.main_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Label(self, text='Please paste your essay below.',
                 font=('Helvetica', 16)).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='ew')
        tk.Label(self, text='Uploading your essay', fg='white', bg='purple',
                 font=('Helvetica', 20)).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='ew')

        self.user_essay_label = tk.Text(self.main_frame)
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        scrollbar.config(command=self.user_essay_label.yview)
        self.user_essay_label.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.user_essay_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        tk.Button(self, text='Quit', fg='purple', font=('Helvetica', 16),
                  command=self.destroy).grid(row=3, column=0)
        tk.Button(self, text='Enter', fg='purple', font=('Helvetica', 16),
                  command=self.essay_window).grid(row=3, column=1)

    def essay_window(self):
        self.main_frame.destroy()
        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.main_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Label(self.main_frame, text='Essay Analysis', fg='white', bg='purple',
                 font=('Helvetica', 20)).pack(fill='x')
        tk.Label(self.main_frame, text=self.user_essay_label.get('1.0', 'end'), fg='white', bg='purple',
                 font=('Helvetica', 16)).place(x=1235, y=600)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    UserInterface().mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes so much more sense